# Why http request taking longer time to respond from angularjs and taking less time to respond when hitting from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

when api is calling from angularjs code its taking longer time to respond.

```
//Api to get page images starts
function GetPageImages(documentID, versionID, startPage, endPage) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

       $http({
           method: 'Get',
           url: drawUtility.baseURL() + '/pageimage/get',
           //url: drawUtility.baseURL() + '/api/pageimage',
           params: {
               docID: documentID,
               versionID: versionID,
               startPage: startPage,
               endPage: endPage
           }
       }).then(function (response) {
           deferred.resolve({
               data: response.data
           })
       }, function (response) {
           var data = response.data,
               status = response.status;
           deferred.reject(data);
           $log.error(status, data);

       });
       return deferred.promise;
 }
 //Api to get page images ends
```

[image]

and when same api is hitting directly from ajax request or in a new tab it is taking less than a second to respond.

What is the reason behind this and what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Could be that the browser is returning a cached result. You could test this is the browser debugging tools by disabling caching (if that is an option in your browser).

Comment: @Igor alternatively, the backend has more overhead for the first request but less for subsequent ones. Either because of cachine or another reason - perhaps the first time you hit the endpoint it also has to establish DB connection but the second time it doesn't.

Comment: yes i have used the empty cache and hard reload but the timing is still less.